# How to reconcile the fact that the antiderivative of $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ has two possible answers?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

So here is the problem.

$$
\int\sin(x)\cos(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x) + c_1 \\
= -\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x) + c_2
$$

This fact doesn't make much sense to me. How do you reconcile the fact that there are two possibilities (notice that these answers aren't only different by a constant)?

What are some other functions that have more than one antiderivatives (not only different by a constant)?

Comment: Just use the trig identity $cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)=1$. The constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ will absorb the 1 in the identity.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog I kinda understand that, but I don't understand what is the correct answer then.

Comment: To put what Sam Weatherhog said more bluntly: those two function do differ by a constant

Comment: Note that $\sin^2 (x) = 1 - \cos^2 (x)$, so indeed with the proper choice of constants your two solutions are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note:

$$
\begin{split} \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)+c_1 &= \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos^2(x))+c_1 \\ &=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)+c_1 \\ &=-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)+c_2  \end{split}
$$

where $c_2=c_1+\frac{1}{2}$. The answers are both the same so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Both answers without the constants are really the same function only different in the y-intercept.

Answer (score 3):

There is no contradiction: it illustrates the fact that trigonometry formulae are polymorphic.

You even have a third answer:
$$-\frac14 \cos2x+\text{constant}.$$

Comment: While this is true, it does not answer the question.  Perhaps it would be better as a comment?

Comment: The answer, as I thought about it, is implicitly in the words *even* and *third*.

Comment: -1 This doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: That's your opinion. For me, it does, as I add one more example that shows there's nothing to reconcile. But maybe you dislike elliptic answers.

Comment: I also agree that this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

> (notice that these answers aren't only different by a constant)

But they *do* differ by a constant.  If you subtract one solution from the other, you have

$$ ( \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)+c_1 ) - ( -\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)+c_2 )$$
which is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2} (\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) ) + c_1 - c_2$$
and using the trig identity $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, all of this is equal to just
$$\frac{1}{2} + c_1 - c_2$$
which is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\ \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, if we let $c_1=c_2-\frac 12$ so we'd have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x) + c_1 &= \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x) + (c_2-\frac 12) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x) + (c_2-\frac 12) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos^2(x)) + (c_2-\frac 12) \\
&= c_2-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)
\end{align}$$